# UNUserNotification never appear when scheduled for later date

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, unnotificationrequest

Notifications are shown when I schedule for a near date in the future, like 1 hour later, but they never show on my real data, when I schedule for tomorrow or for later tonight. Any ideas on why this is happening? I double checked the trigger.nextTriggerDate(), they are right

Here's my code:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class func scheduleWith(episode: Episode, dateInfo: DateComponents) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = episode.title
    content.body = episode.overview

    content.userInfo = ["id": episode.id]
    content.categoryIdentifier = Notify.category.episodes.str

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateInfo, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: Notify.identifier.episode.str, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        else {
            print("date info", dateInfo.date)
            print("trigger", trigger.nextTriggerDate()!)
        }
    })
}
```

And here's how I'm creating the dateInfo:

```
let greg = Calendar.current
var components = DateComponents()
components.setValue(-15, for: .minute)

guard let date = ep.firstAired as Date? else { return }
guard let alertDate = greg.date(byAdding: components, to: date) else { return }

let dateInfo = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second], from: alertDate)
```

Comment: Why not simply  `greg.date(byAdding: DateComponents(minute: -15), to: date)`

Comment: and `let dateInfo = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second], from: alertDate)`

Comment: BTW shouldn't it be `guard let date = ep.firstAired as Date? else { return }` Are you sure firstAired is the correct Date?

Comment: From docs: "The continue statement tells a loop to stop what it is doing and start again at the beginning of the next iteration through the loop."

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the firstAired is correct, if you check out again my question, I explained that "trigger.nextTriggerDate()" is printing the exact date I would like to receive the notification

Comment: You are not showing any loop

Comment: It's not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Well if your trigger date shows correct it should be triggered

Comment: Considering you are in a loop just to remind you need a different identifier for each notification. It is not clear if you are using the same or not

Comment: Hmmm, that's it, thanks. I'm creating all notifications with the same identifer! That's why only one is triggering, thank you very much!

"identifier: Notify.identifier.episode.str"

Comment: Please answer this so I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same identifier for your notifications. You need to specify a different identifier to each notification inside your loop.